# Optimize code with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to optimize my code and I found out about comprehensions. But I am struggling with my code and how to apply dictionary comprehension.
The original code is below.

How do I optimize this code in a proper pythonic way?

```py
all_users = []
for x in range(len(result)):
    user = {}
    user["fieldy"] = str(result[x][1].get("valueforfield1", None))[3:-2]
    user["fieldx"] = str(result[x][1].get("valueforfield2", None))[3:-2]
    user["fieldc"] = str(result[x][1].get("valueforfield3", None))[3:-2]
    user["fieldv"] = str(result[x][1].get("valueforfield4", None))[3:-2]
    user["fieldb"] = str(result[x][1].get("valueforfield5", None))[3:-2]
    all_users.append(user)
```

example value of result

```py
result = [('CN=Xxx X,OU=X,OU=X,DC=X,DC=X', {'valueforfield1': [b'Va'], 'valueforfield2': [b'val'], 'valueforfield3': [b'+123'], 'valueforfield4': [b'65@test.com'], 'valueforfield5': [b'examplevalue']}),('CN=Yyy Y,OU=Y,OU=Y,DC=Y,DC=Y', {'valueforfield1': [b'Ycx'], 'valueforfield2': [b'Dy'], 'valueforfield3': [b'+321'], 'valueforfield4': [b'64@test.com'], 'valueforfield5': [b'examplevaluey']})]
```

after the code is executed the `user` dictionary have following content after the first iteration of for loop

```
{"fieldy": "Va", "fieldx": "val", "fieldc": "+123", "fieldv": "65@test.com", "fieldb": "examplevalue"}
```

Also should I write a function to replace the `user["field1"] = str(result[x][1].get("valueforfield1", None))[3:-2]` code? Is it worth it and recommended?
Thanks!

Comment: What is `result` ?

Comment: You can't really optimise it in terms of speed, only in making the code more concise

Comment: post your `result` value

Comment: sorry, updated.

Comment: @jv95, Ok, how do you define that `fieldy` corresponds to `valueforfield1`? by what criteria?

Comment: by its name. `fieldy` will always take value from `valueforfield1`. `valueforfield1` is a name of key in a dictionary from `result`.

Comment: I mean, you said that the only static thing in `result` is key like `valueforfield1`. Then how the word `fieldy` is getting constructed? Should it be the ending part from key `valueforfield1`:  after `valuefor` --> `field1` ?

Comment: `fieldy` is a hardcoded name. Its not constructed by any code. Its a name I gave to the key. I hope I got your question right.?

Comment: Do you confirm that the following `{"fieldy": "valueforfield1", "fieldx": "valueforfield2",
                       "fieldc": "valueforfield3", "fieldv": "valueforfield4",
                       "fieldb": "valueforfield5", "fieldn": "valueforfield6",
                       }` is the right mapping for conformity?

Comment: The value in key `fieldy` should be `Va` , `fieldx` should be `Val` and so .. Note that the KEY `fieldy` is taking the VALUE from the dic where KEY is `valueforfield1` . I hope its clear now?

Comment: is that your confirmation? You don't see the end values while planning processing, but you should establish keys conformity beforehand

Comment: Yes, it is my confirmation. I set my key name `fieldy` and then I add a value to it. The value is taken from key `valueforfield1` which is taken from `result` . `valueforfield1`  will always be in `result` .

Comment: Ok, will provide a solution in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With well-factored approach:

```
result = [('CN=Xxx X,OU=X,OU=X,DC=X,DC=X',
           {'valueforfield1': [b'Va'], 'valueforfield2': [b'val'], 'valueforfield3': [b'+123'],
            'valueforfield3': [b'65@test.com'], 'valueforfield5': [b'examplevalue']}),
          ('CN=Yyy Y,OU=Y,OU=Y,DC=Y,DC=Y',
           {'valueforfield1': [b'Ycx'], 'valueforfield2': [b'Dy'],
            'valueforfield3': [b'+321'], 'valueforfield3': [b'64@test.com'],
            'valueforfield5': [b'examplevaluey']})]

def compose_user_details(data):
    keys_map = {"fieldy": "valueforfield1", "fieldx": "valueforfield2",
                "fieldc": "valueforfield3", "fieldv": "valueforfield4",
                "fieldb": "valueforfield5", "fieldn": "valueforfield6",
                }
    user_details = []

    for i in range(len(result)):
        dataset = result[i][1]  # getting the needed `data source` at once
        user_details.append({k: str(dataset.get(v, None))[3:-2]
                             for k,v in keys_map.items()})
    return user_details

print(compose_user_details(result))
```

The output:

```
[{'fieldy': 'Va', 'fieldx': 'val', 'fieldc': '65@test.com', 'fieldv': '', 'fieldb': 'examplevalue', 'fieldn': ''}, {'fieldy': 'Ycx', 'fieldx': 'Dy', 'fieldc': '64@test.com', 'fieldv': '', 'fieldb': 'examplevaluey', 'fieldn': ''}]
```

Comment: @jv95, you're welcome. You can remove `"fieldn": "valueforfield6"` item from `keys_map` if it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using just a dict comprehension to take care of the repeating code:

```
all_users = []
for x in range(len(result)):
    user = {f"field{i}": str(result[x][1].get(f"valueforfield{i}", None))[3:-2] for i in range(1, 7)}
    all_users.append(user)
```

Using both a list comprehension and a dict comprehension to do it all in one line:

```
all_users = [{
        f"field{i}": str(result[x][1].get(f"valueforfield{i}", None))[3:-2] 
        for i in range(1, 7)
    } for x in range(len(result))]
```

The difficulty in the example you provided comes in the names of the keys - but since those are regular, I used a format string to just insert the integer that the key expects (that is, `f"field{i}"` resolves to `"field1"` when `i = 1`, `"field2"` when `i = 2`, and so on).

---

In general, comprehensions don't really optimize for speed - they're more for avoiding code reuse.

Comment: Thats really nice looking solution. But what would you do if the names would not be so nice? I have another part of code with the same issue but the names are like.. fieldexample should het value from valueforexamplefield  and so on... here I cant use your  "field1" when i = 1, "field2" when i = 2   how would you solve it? I didnt post the code because I thought I could use the solution for both loops i have

Comment: @jv95, why don't you post a representative, testable input structure?

Comment: @jv95 if you want to use comprehension on that data, you'll need to come up with a system to identify what key should correspond to what value. You could, for example, use a hardcoded `dict` of index to key, and put that in the format string - e.g. `my_dict={1:'y', 2:'x', ...}` and then `f"field{my_dict[i]}"`. Or come up with some other workable solution to that issue

Comment: Thats not possible since result will be different every time I run the code. Basically the whole idea behind this, is to create dictionaries in `all_users` and fill these dictionaries with values from `result` . the `result` length and values will be different every time. The only static thing in result is the key name as `valueforfield1`  etc

Comment: @jv95 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499932/python-dictionary-compehension#comment99590072_56499932